# Easiest full text search engine for a small corpus with proximity search

Tags: web-apps, web-development, search-engine, text-processing, text-search

I'm creating a full text search engine for a series of approximately 10 public domain books. The corpus will *rarely* be updated. Proximity search will be the core feature, e.g. locating "hello" within 5 words of "world".

I'm looking at both Haystack for Django/Python and Ruby solutions. I'm aware of: Solr, Elasticsearch, Whoosh, Xapian, and Sphinx.

With such a small corpus I'm focused on ease of implementation, and right now I'm leaning toward Whoosh (pure Python) or Sphinx (with Haystack or maybe Ruby on Rails). Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a definition for "word A near word B"? Does "near" mean within 3 words before or after word B? Within 5 words? Is the "nearness" definable by the user?

Comment: It would be ideal if it were definable by the user. Even just "in the same chapter" would be sufficient though. Same paragraph or a specific # of words apart would be even better but not strictly required.

Comment: I think the feature you mean is called [proximity search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_search_%28text%29).

Comment: @unor that has narrowed me down quite a bit. I might try out Whoosh after noting in its documentation that it supports proximity search, and I already have a Django setup. Thanks!

Comment: Actually realized Ruby might be better suited for my needs, and noted Sphinx has paragraph, sentence, and just "nearby" proximity searches, awesome! http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/extended-syntax.html Might use that. I'll answer my own question here once I really start implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with Python, Flask, Whoosh, and gunicorn. It was an absolute cinch, I had it running almost immediately, and the Python nativity of Whoosh has been quite nice. Very advanced search, easy additions. Perfect for my small corpus.

I've completed and [published the code](https://github.com/CodeOptimist/whoosh-galpin) for my engine. Here is a [**live demonstration**](https://findingseth.com). Read my [introductory article](https://medium.com/@christopher.galpin/document-search-engine-d68238259a00) for more details, and if I write any further articles for this project they will be listed [on my site](https://codeoptimism.com/#81).

Here's a [reference to proximity search](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querylang.html#individual-terms-and-phrases) with Whoosh's query language.

Comment: this is amazing. What files would I be looking at if I wanted to repurpose your script with a different corpus?

Comment: @StefanoMorello Thanks for asking! I actually have a lot of unpublished improvements to the repo, and just recently re-setup my dev environment for this project. I have been on a streak of publishing everything that has languished on my drive. I've updated the link in the repo _About_ section to a Discord invite for this specific project where I may be of some help; alternatively "Watch" the repo for a future guide. 